# How can I modify this code to make the heapSort sort in descending order?

Tags: c++, heapsort

I want this heapSort to sort in descending order but I cant figure out where I am going wrong. I just cant figure out why my heapSort keeps sorting in ascending order rather than descending.

```
void fixheapD(int a[], int left, int right, int& count) {
    int x = a[left];
    int i, j;
    for (i = left, j = 2 * i + 1; j <= right; i = j, j = 2 * i + 1) {
        if (j < right) {
            if (a[j + 1] > a[j]) j++;
            count++;
        }
        if (x >= a[j]) {
            count++;
            break;
        }
        a[i] = a[j];
    }
    a[i] = x;
}
void heapSortD(int a[], int n, int& countP1, int& countP2) {
    if (n > 1) {
        for (int left = n / 2 - 1; left >= 0; left--) {
            fixheapD(a, left, n - 1, countP1);
        }

        std::swap(a[0], a[n - 1]);
        for (int right = n - 2; right >= 1; right--) {
            fixheapD(a, 0, right, countP2);
            std::swap(a[0], a[right]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried swapping `<` for `>`?

Comment: `if (a[j + 1] > a[j])`  -- If you are saying you already tried changing `>` to `<`, and it still doesn't work correctly, maybe you should consider rewriting your sorting function so that there is only a single place where simply changing the sort criteria changes how the sort works.  That's how most good functions that sort data are written.